# What is the syntax for SqlAdditionalArguments in SqlAzureDacpacDeployment

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, devops, dacpac

I am trying to run SqlAzureDacpacDeployment in Azure DevOps to execute sql file and pass variables.

I have defined variables in sql file using $(Database).

```
USE '$(Database)'
GO
    SELECT name FROM dbo.names where name = '$(Name)'
GO
```

yaml definition below, I am not sure how to put SqlAdditionalArguments, below one is not working

```
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
      displayName: 'Run SQL'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'test'
        AuthenticationType: servicePrincipal
        ServerName: 'database.windows.net'
        DatabaseName: dev
        deployType: SqlTask
        SqlFile: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s/scripts/SqlNames.sql'
        SqlAdditionalArguments: -Database='dev' -Name='test123'
```

What is the syntax for variables in SqlAdditionalArguments

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it like described below:

following file exists `scripts\test.sql` with following content:

```
SELECT $(MYVAR1) AS Var1, $(MYVAR2) AS Var2
```

you can execute SQL from a file providing parameter values

for Azure SQL like this:

```
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: MyServiceConnection
    AuthenticationType: 'servicePrincipal'
    ServerName: MyServerName
    DatabaseName: MyDatabaseName
    deployType: 'SqlTask'
    SqlFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\scripts\test.sql'
    SqlAdditionalArguments: -Variable "MYVAR1='String1'", "MYVAR2='String2'"
```

for SQL Server on a machine like this:

```
- task: SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  inputs:
    TaskType: 'sqlQuery'
    SqlFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\scripts\test.sql'
    ServerName: '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB'
    DatabaseName: 'master'
    AuthScheme: 'windowsAuthentication'
    AdditionalArgumentsSql: -Variable "MYVAR1='String1'", "MYVAR2='String2'"
```

Answer (score 0):

The doc says it's [Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps)

> (Optional) Additional Invoke-Sqlcmd arguments that will be applied
> when executing the given SQL query on the Azure SQL Database like,
> -ConnectionTimeout 100 -OutputSqlErrors

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-azure-dacpac-deployment?view=azure-devops

Comment: When I am using this syntax `-Database "dev" -Name "test123"` I get this error  Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'Database' is specified more than once. Still it cannot accept the second parameter

Comment: Database is already in the yaml.

Comment: well I tired with single parameter `-Name "test123` and error A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Name'. There must be something special about this, maybe it is defined incorrectly in the script.

Comment: Name is not a valid argument for invoke-sqlcmd

Comment: So what I should put in sql file I thought they go into format `$(<variable>)` and then in invoke `-variable "someValue"` ?

Comment: Follow the doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps#example-3--invoke-a-script-and-pass-in-variable-values-from-a-string

Comment: I will try that, but last attempt failed

Comment: I am afraid it is not working there is either a bug or documentation is not up to date.